# Select a form option by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm looking for, in Django, a generated form from database could be picked just by clicking on it. In `forms.py`, I have picked the form to be radio selected with `widget=RadioSelect`.

In my template I've added the code that if I pick an option (click on the radio of the option), it automatically picks up the correct answer (which is what I want), but with no radio option (so, choosing the answer by clicking on the text). I have coded the previously mentioned method just like this:

```
<form id="game" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type=hidden name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">

  <ul class="group-cm">

    {% for answer in form.answers %}
      <div id="answers"><li onclick="game.submit();" class="listing-cm">
        {{ answer }}
      </li></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So, how could I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any clue on what should I do to eliminate the radius button and make the text act like it?

Comment: I'm looking around the net and I can't find anything like this... there must be an option to do it. Anyone know how would it work? Thank you....